# Gmail contacts not syncing - How to get them to sync?

Tags: gmail

I have a new Samsung S8+ and Gmail seems not to find any contacts when I try to compose an email. I have downloaded google contacts and all contacts appear on my phone. Is there a setting I've missed?

Comment: http://www.droidforums.net/threads/when-does-google-sync-contacts.14278/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the permission for Gmail to view contacts is most probably off.
Go into settings>manage applications>Gmail>permissions>contacts on

(Worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on "automatically sync data" on your device

Answer (score -1):

You can go through Settings > Accounts > Google > Gmail and turning on the sync button.